# Executing other tasks even if one task fails in SSIS BIDS 2008 R2

Tags: ssis

I have a Data Flow Task and then there are two Execute Sql Tasks which follow the DFT. I want the Execute Sql Tasks to still run even if there is an error in the DFT. 
I am aware I can do this by redirecting the erroneous records to some log file and set the option to Ignore Failure. But I'd like to perform this without the need for an error log.
I have set the MaximumErrorCount of the DFT to a considerable large value but this only helped in getting me the parent green but the Sql Tasks did not run.
I have also tried setting the OnError event for this DFT such that the value of Propagate variable is set to False. 
But still no luck.

Any ideas/suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: set the Precedence Constraint in a certain way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you alluded to  in your comment,  you need to double click the connector line from the data flow to your  execute sql  task and change the precedence constraint from  success to  completion.